# spliting autocomplete value into 2 string for php function

Tags: php, jquery, html

The values in the Autocomplete are first name and last name. I need to divide them into two strings, `fn` and `ln`, and send them to a PHP function to calculate the result.

I'm not sure how to separate the name into two values and send them to another PHP function which calculates the relation between these two people need their first name and last name to determine their id.

```html
<html>
<?php include ('relation.php');?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#fname").autocomplete({
        source: 'mysql.php'
      });
    });

    $(function() {
      $("#fname2").autocomplete({
        source: 'mysql.php'
      });
    });
  </script>
  <div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="skills">fist person: </label>
    <input id="fname">
  </div>
  <div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="skills">second person </label>
    <input id="fname2">
  </div>
  <div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="skills">Skills: </label>
    <button id="search" onclick="">
  </div>
?>
</html>
```

```php
<?php
  //database configuration
  $dbHost = 'localhost:3308';
  $dbUsername = 'root';
  $dbPassword = '';
  $dbName = 'village';

  //connect with the database
  $db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);

  //get search term
  $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

  //get matched data from skills table
  $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM individual WHERE fname LIKE 
 '%".$searchTerm."%'");
  while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row['fname']." ".$row['lname'];
  }

  //return json data
  echo json_encode($data);
 ?>

//relation.php


function calculate_relationship($a_id, $b_id)



function aggrandize_relationship($rel, $dist, $offset = 0) {

function lowest_common_ancestor($a_id, $b_id)
function lowest_common_ancestor($a_id, $b_id)
function get_ancestors($id, $dist = 0)
```

.....

```
function getid($fname,$lname){
   $conn = OpenCon();
   get matched data from skills table
  $query = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM individual WHERE fname LIKE 
 '%".$fname."%' and lname LIKE '%".$lname."%'");
  $row = $query->fetch_row();


    return $row[0];8*/


   }
  if( $_GET['fn1'] && $_GET['ln1']&&$_GET['fn2'] && $_GET['ln2']) {



$relation=calculate_relationship(getid($_GET['fn1'],$_GET['ln1']),getid($_GET['f 
            n2'],$_GET['ln2']));
          } 



//$relation=calculate_relationship($_GET['fn1'],$_GET['fn2']);
if($relation!='')
echo   "  a is the " .$relation." of b ";

else
echo "There's no relation between a and b ";
```

Comment: where is your PHP code?

Comment: you can split first_name and last_name if there is a space in between them.

Comment: add your relation.php file's code

Comment: there is a  space btwween them but if i split them how would i storw them to send them fro another php file

Comment: you can send them as 2 parameters into different php page..